# Is there any difference in using a font Arial Black or Arial with the <Strong> tag?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My text that is supposed to be Arial Black is not working on Firefox. It's just displayed as a regular text. So I used Arial font with the `Strong` tag. I can't make a difference between the way they look. Is there anything I should worry about?

Thank you

**EDIT**

In this particular case I can't use CSS to do it so that's how i did it:

```
<font face="Arial Black, Arial, sans-serif"> <strong>Want an undergraduate course with more opportunity for hands-on practice? </strong></font>
```

Thanks for all the answers and explanations, I believe the strong tag is not wrong here as this is the most important part in the whole message. The visual difference wasn't noticed by anybody, that's confirmation enough for me.

I posted in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Uhky/5/) and it surprised me the strong tag didn't add the bold effect i was expecting! The `b` did. You can clearly see the difference there! Thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: Could you post a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net? Plus add the code here too ([edit]) :)

Comment: Try to post the CSS code you use for the font. Using the <strong> tag is not bad, just be sure it does add a semantic level of importance.

Comment: Do you have 'Arial Black' installed on your machine?

Comment: Added the jsfiddle. I can't use css in this page specifically but the semantic importance is good on this case! And yes, I have Arial black installed, it works on ie, chrome but not on firefox!

Comment: The `strong` tag is not bold in jsFiddle because they added this to their reset stylesheet (http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css). Normally, this won’t be a problem.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert oh, that's another thing i'd never notice :) thanks a lot for that!!

Comment: @gameowner To answer your original question: there IS a difference between putting Arial in bold and using Arial Black: black is actually an even heavier font-weight than bold. If you don’t see a difference between the two, it’s probably because your font-size is too small to distinguish the two weights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With regard to the question title (as the question text seems to ask differently):

The `<strong>` tag carries a semantic meaning. [Citing MDN on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/strong)

> The HTML Strong Element () gives text strong importance, and is typically displayed in bold.

So in the first place you should use this tag so mark up content, that you want to emphasize and not to get text marked bold.

Most browsers, however, will implement that emphasizing as just bold printed text.

If you just want to have bold text, use the respective CSS for it!

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Comment: Thank you for that, together with @Heena Hussain answer I have excelent reasons to use the font-weight style!

Comment: I'll take yours as the right answer, from all the options I based myself mostly this "most browsers" to make my choice on what to use. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

`<strong>` holds a certain semantic meaning (along the lines of "more important"), and as such should be avoided purely to style something. If you want to "bold" the text, just add `font-weight: 700`.

Or you know, fix the reason Arial Black isn't working :P It may be that you didn't add speech marks around Arial Black.

`font-family: Arial;`

is completely acceptable, but

`font-family: Arial Black;`

is not. Make sure you have

`font-family: "Arial Black";`

Comment: I posted what I'm using, you are saying I should use face="Arial Black", "Arial", "sans-serif" ?

Comment: Yes, that should work if that is the issue (it looks like it is)

Comment: Still gives me nothing on firefox. But with or without quotes I'm fine on IE and chrome!

Comment: Try this instead, wrap the text in a span and do `<span style="font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a considerable difference in using Arial Black vs. Arial with the `strong` element. I will answer in CSS terms, substituting the CSS setting `font-weight: bolder` for HTML `strong` markup. (It's really irrelevant here whether you call for bold face directly in CSS or indirectly with HTML markup that implies a certain default setting.)

It is not clear what you mean by “Arial Black is not working on Firefox”.

The most logical CSS code for the purpose would be:

```
font-family: Arial; font-weight: 900;
```

This asks for the boldest available font in the Arial font family; that’s Arial Black when available, or else Arial Bold. Firefox does not seem to support this quite consistently, but many browsers have even more serious problems with font heights. (E.g., Chrome shows weight 600 as bolder than 700.)

In practice it is safer to use the old kludgy way, which refers to a specific font (typeface) as if it were a font family:

```
font-family: Arial Black;
```

For example, on IE 8, this is the only way to get Arial Black, whereas IE 9 supports the logical way, too (in “Standards Mode”).

If you use set the font to Arial and font weight to `bolder`, you get Arial Bold. If you set `font-family: Arial Black` and `font-weight: bolder`, you get Arial Black, because there is no bolder font. And Arial Bold and Arial Black are very different.

It’s impossible to say what went wrong in your first attempts, as you did not post the actual code used.

Comment: Thanks for this, very clarifying. I confused Arial Black with Arial Bold. In the end it worked in every browser with Arial bold and it was what they wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would receive the same effect, however I would recommend using CSS styling instead of using the strong tag.

```
.arial-black{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no visual difference between the `<strong>`, `<b>` and `font-weight:700|bold;`.

However `<strong>` is used by screen readers (for the blind and partially sighted) to put emphasis on the text... therefore using a "bold" font will not result in the same thing for screen readers.

If you don't want to "emphasis" the text for screen readers, then I would recommend you use the `<b>` tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

`<strong>` tag does not support all browsers, as Arial and Arial black is concerned both are different in size or weight you can say.

So answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the font Arial Black in a web page only works for the users that actually have that font installed. (Of course, using Arial also only works on systems that have that font).

Arial Black is not just a bold version of Arial. Although similar, Arial Black has a different look than the bold version of Arial:

[Arial, bold](http://www.911fonts.com/font/download_ArialBold_603.htm)
[Arial Black](http://www.911fonts.com/font/download_ArialBlackRegular_608.htm)

You should use a fallback font for all fonts that you use, so that the browser knows what to use if that specific font isn't available, however it's tricky to use a font that is bold by default, as you can't specify `Arial bold` as fallback for `Arial Black`. You would have to make do with using `Arial` as fallback:

```
font-family: 'Arial Black', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `@font-face` rule to force Arial Black whenever the bold `font-weight` of Arial is used:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
    /* You can add other common names using comma-separated local definitions here */
    src: local('Arial Black');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
    src: local('Arial');
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Now, whenever Arial is set as the font for an element and the calculated font weight is `bold` (which is what user agents set for the `string` tag in their `html.css` definitions), Arial Black is used instead.

Comment: I’ve modified your demonstration with my technique: http://jsfiddle.net/7Uhky/10/.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option for me, I can't use CSS on this specific page. But thanks, i'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @gameowner if you can edit the HTML, you can also inject CSS. Just use a `<style>` tag. They used to be restricted to the `<head>` but with the `scoped` attribute being discussed for HTML5, this restriction was dropped, and considering that the browsers all render styles included this way just fine, that was a sensible decision.

Comment: That's not open to discussion with them. I CAN'T use CSS, it's a requirement for the project. I can apply styles to elements but not a <style> tag.

Comment: Ah, requirements! Sometimes I forget about The Real World™…

Comment: Pain in the arse. But what can we do. We need food on our table :).

Answer (score -4):

strong tag basically creates your text in bold. For your case it makes no difference. But it will create a difference if your font is different and you are using "strong"